# Google map with KML layer display bug in IE 6 / 8

Tags: internet-explorer, kml, google-maps-markers

I've had some client complaints that using IE 8, the map on their site is not displaying correctly. I've tried it in IE 9 and it works along with Opera, Chrome, Firefox etc.

[Heres the map in question](http://www.rugbywindfarm.com.au/section/interactive_map/)

I ran it in IETester (close as I can get to a running IE 8) and it looks fine in IE 8, but does not display right in the IE 6 tab. Can anyone with IE 8 confirm this issue for me.

And anyone with any ideas about what could be causing this weird display issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API v3 isn't supported for older browsers, see: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2010/03/supported-browser-updates-for-maps-api.html

Which is annoying if you are a user who is forced to use IE6 (I work at the State Government of Victoria - back in the dark ages)

I'm not sure if you could try redeveloping in V2 but I figure you'd need a V2 ID for that.

Otherwise you will have to tell your users to upgrade - or stop using IE.

Regards,

Lea.
ps: Good luck with the Windfarms!